# Xamarin Forms entity framework core database does not get created

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to set up an sqlite database with EF Core in xamarin forms. Currently I'm only interested in making it work for Android.

What I've done so far:

Created a migration with **add-migration init** using a mock console app as startup project. It is in the same namespace and project as the datacontext file.

DataContext gets initialized with autofac, the database path is

**System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData + filename.db**

called **DataBase.Migrate()** in datacontext constructor

The problem is, that when I debug the application in android emulator, and try and get or add something to the dbset, it throws an exception saying the table does not exist.

When I check the folder in androids Files App, there is no .local folder created in the application's folder, and I can't find the sqlite file anywhere. I've also tried setting the path to the personal folder instead, to no avail.

During debugging, the context gets initialized properly, and the Database.Migrate() method runs without any thrown exceptions aswell.

```
public DataContext(string databasePath)
        {
            DatabasePath = databasePath;
            Database.Migrate();
        }

public DbSet<PageContent> PageContents { get; set; }

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={DatabasePath}");
        }
```

Comment: do you have file access permissions set appropriately, and are you using a valid path?  Hint - take the time to read the docs and using the Android file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out JeePakaJP's answer, it worked. But I found out that it works without manually creating the file with File.Create aswell.

The problem was that Visual Studio didn't rebuild the project for some reason.

Also, the file won't show in the file explorer app just because of user permissions, but it's actually there.

Comment: It seems that you have one solution, if yes, please remember to mark helpful post as answer, thanks

Comment: it doesn't seem to me

Answer (score 0):

Try to create db file

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string databasePath;
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();

                    string docFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    string libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library", "Databases");

                    if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
                    }

                    databasePath = Path.Combine(libFolder, databaseName) ;
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Platform not supported");
            }

            if (!File.Exists(databasePath))
                File.Create(databasePath);

            // Specify that we will use sqlite and the path of the database here
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={databasePath}");
        }
```